# Android Studio 2.3: libraries must use the exact same exact specification

Tags: android, ide, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-studio-2.3

After updating to android studio 2.3 gradle warning me like this, and I can't install my app to emulator.

libraries must use the exact same exact specification

[image: [libraries must use the exact same exact specification]]

Comment: Please post your project full build.gradle file and all your module's build.gradle file which contains dependencies added.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the link @Soham